# Usage of the suffix o-meter in compound words like: busy-o-meter, happy-o-meter

Tags: informal-language

Someone on another website was wondering whether a certain word was correct. After they asked the question they said:

> I guess I'm asking how it rates on the **correct-o-meter**.

The usage of *correct-o-meter* got me curious to know more about this unusual yet interesting usage of the suffix *o-meter*.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/-ometer)'s definition:

> *informal*
> Forming nouns denoting a measure of a quality, emotion, etc.
>
> *Examples:*    ‘stressometer’ ‘drunkometer’

I have also found many variations of it:

- Truth-o-meter
- Fake-o-meter
- Lie-o-meter
- Weird-o-meter
- Epic-o-meter
- Busy-o-meter
- Happy-o-meter
- Cringe-o-meter
- Surprise-o-meter

and many more.
Some are obviously trademarks of actual measuring tools, however, I am particularly interested in the ones that indicate imaginary measuring tools like: *happy-o-meter*.

My question is:
Do native speakers usually add the suffix *o-meter* to a word for a humorous effect?
I mean I would assume that, for example, *cringe-o-meter* and *epic-o-meter* could only be used in a humorous context.
Is this correct? If so, could you please give me an example sentence for this specific usage?

Comment: AFAIK, these are all rather unusual terms, synthesized when needed for humor. No, I would say this is not often used, though the meaning of each would be easily understood.

Comment: You have the recipe, you know how to make new examples. Some people might do it now and then, but someone who invented a new -o-meter expression every five minutes would soon find themselves being avoided if not subjected to physical violence.

Comment: This topic is thoroughly covered, as a trope, [here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThingOMeter) - "basically Whatever-You-Want-O-Meter". Has an example from 1727.

Comment: @Michael Harvey "Some people might do it now and then, but someone who invented a new -o-meter expression every five minutes would soon find themselves being avoided if not subjected to physical violence." :) That paints a hilarious mental picture.               Thank you for the link, I have checked out several pages on that website and it gave me some good insighs on how trope works. I'm currently trying to come up with examples. I think I'm going to add them to the OP soon.

Answer (score 3):

> Q. Do native speakers usually add the suffix o-meter to a word for a humorous effect?

I wouldn't say we do it a *lot*, but it is a recognisable trope as your research has proved. Of course, there are many legitimate, real-life things with the suffix such as a *barometer*, or a *speedometer*. Also, many old television programmes would feature a 'clapometer' which supposedly measured the level of applause from the studio audience.

There's something very old-fashioned about it - even though 'meters' for measuring things are very much still in use, it sounds like something from the pre-digital, analogue age. Part of the humour also derives from the anachronistic feel.

Some other suffixes which are also used for similar humorous effect include:

- "**-omatic**" - to suggest automation, eg 'grillomatic' for an automatic grilling machine. Heavily used for humour in the *Wallace and Gromit* films.
- "**-inator**" - to suggest that something brings about an effect in something, or causes something to become something, heavily used in the cartoon series 'Phineas and Ferb'. Also sometimes used as a suffix to someone's name to suggest they are unstoppable like 'The Terminator'.